# Unable to check if ImageView is contains image

Tags: java, android, imageview

I want to be able to check if an `ImageView` contains an image when a button is pressed. My `ImageView` is surrounded by a `CardView`.

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/cardViewAE"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200sp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@color/colorIV"
                    />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I've declared the imageView appropriately in my main java class.

```
ImageView flyerImageView;
flyerImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

I do an if statement to check if the imageView is null, however, even when there is no image inside the imageView it does not execute the code inside that if statement.

```
submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            TextView errorLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.errorTV);

            if (flyerImageView.getDrawable() == null){
                errorLabel.setText("You forgot to choose your event flyer.");
            }
     }
```

Comment: show your Logcat

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean ishaveImage = (imageView.getDrawable() != null);

if (ishaveImage) {
    // image available
} else {
    // no image available
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
publie static boolean hasNullOrEmptyDrawable(ImageView iv)
{
Drawable drawable = iv.getDrawable();
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable ;
if(drawable!=null)
bitmapDrawable= drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable ? (BitmapDrawable)drawable : null;

return drawable==null || bitmapDrawable == null || bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() == null;
}
```